# civi "triangle" menu missing

Tags: menu

The upper left triangle civi logo should show Hide option and quick menu search.  But it is missing from menu - see image - Is there a settting to show this
[image]

Comment: Try clearing the cache?

Comment: I did, no luck.

Comment: It would be useful to have more detaiils. Has it ever worked? Have you upgraded? Etc.

Comment: yes, it has worked.   We run over 20 instances for clients.  This is the only one that shows this problem.  Possibly a Civi theming issue?

Comment: The issue shows up in prior version - 5.33  and now in 5.39 testing